# Complete Current Statement behaves differently in Scala in IntelliJ

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, code-completion

I recently upgraded my IDEA and now using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2 Ultimate Edition.
I found the `Complete Current Statement` in Scala code behaves differently as in Java code, which is very annoying. [image: inmenu]

For example in Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String foo = "bar"
}
```

Press `Complete Current Statement` shortcut(shift+cmd+enter for me) anywhere in line #2, will add a `;` at the end of the line, and an auto-indent will be applied too:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String foo = "bar";
}
```

Then press `Complete Current Statement` again will bring you to a new line when there is nothing more to adjust.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String foo = "bar";
    
}
```

In previous version of IntelliJ, I roughly remember the behavior is same for Scala code.
But in this version of IntelliJ, when I try to do samething in Scala code, for example:

```
  def foo (): Unit = {
throw new RuntimeException
  }
```

When I press `Complete Current Statement` in line #2, nothing happens.

Could anyone please help me checkout why or how should I config to align with Java code's behavior? Thank you very much!

Comment: Why would you want to add semicolon at the end of the line? That's not a good practice in Scala, you almost never need those semicolons.

Comment: Is this a question or a bug report? Do you want to redirect this to jetbrains bug tracker?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! My focusing point is to **move my cursor to next line** with this line auto-indented, which is not achievable with current behaivor in Scala code. Above is just an example, and of course, I don't expect this `Complete Current Statement` function to add a semicolon for Scala code.

Comment: Hi @SimY4, I don't know if this is a bug or not introduced by new version of intellij, just behavior discrepancy between languages. More like a question I guess?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use that in Scala because semicolons are optional, and almost never used. Actually, your Scala code sample is already what you would call a "complete statement".

For formatting what I do and recommend is having set `File` -> `Settings` -> `Tools` -> `Actions on save` and check `Reformat code` and optionally `Optimize imports`, and it will do both whenever you save your source file using `Ctrl + S`. I believe it's `Cmd + S` on your Mac.

This uses the default Intellij Formatter for Scala. Scala also has it's own Formatter called [Scalafmt](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/) with customizable setups more control of formatting different Scala features based on your preferences. This is located at `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Code Style` -> `Scala`.

If for some reason you would still like to use your shortcut key, then the only thing the `Complete current statement` can do to your Scala code is auto-indenting the current line, which for some reason it doesn't so it seems to be a bug on Intellij's side. But what you can do is replace the `Auto-Indent Lines` shortcut key to use your `Complete current statement` shortcut key instead and get the same behavior.